# deleted plugins in wordpress still showing in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I am using a free hosting provider (bytehost) earlier i was using wordpress on this url (site url and wordpress url were both - http://harshitladdha.byethost7.com) 
Now after completion i bought a domain - http://the19a.com so changed the wordpress url and site url accordingly.
Now the trouble occurred when i was trying to upload some fonts and use them, i always got the error of file not found, but i fixed permissions, uploaded the font twice and still the same result.
Now what i dont understand is after that i searched for some plugins to install and uploaded them in my servers folder, but in my dashboard i did not find any plugins except the old one
So, i tried disabling all old ones and deleted every plugin from my plugins folder and to my surprise when i went to my dashboard and checked all plugins , they were all there not deleted, i dont know what is happening ? can anyone help and tell whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

you should upload and delete your plugins in /wp-content/plugins/ folder with FTP client (I had similar problems). After you upload them just click activate in Dashboard :)

Comment: I uploaded through FTP only, then went and checked if they were there or not through web-client and then deleted them, but they are still showing up in dashboard

Comment: Then this is problem with DB, have a look in plugin do you have on bottom some button for delete or you need go in DB and delete tables for this plugin.

Comment: i dont think its the db issue, because i tried deleting the plugins from my dashboard and went to filezilla to see if the plugin is still there and to my surprise it is still there, not deleted. I just dont get whats happening here

Comment: If you are using Sftp in hosting this could be problem, WP is working perfect just with Ftp . As I told you I was uploading plugins or deleting them trough FTP client and then activated them in Dashboard.